# Powerbuilder messagebox text

Tags: messagebox, powerbuilder

When you use MessageBox you have a selection of MessageBoxButtons to choose from.
The buttons available are an enum, and give you options like "Yes No", "OK Cancel", etc.

When I am using, for instance, Hungarian message text the user still gets the English "Yes No".

Is there a way to change the text of the buttons (in Powerbuilder) so that the language is correct?
Can I override the text, or set the current locale in some way so that I can have "Igen Nem" instead of "Yes No"?

It is ok on my local machine, but in the RDS enviroment the options are "Yes/No" again.
What should I do on the RDS machine?

Thanks